# Why does WMS not load with addWMSTiles() in R leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I have a WMS which could be loaded in QGIS, but not with leaflet in R.

Does someone see what I am doing wrong?

The WMS URL is as follows:

http://www.umweltkarten.mv-regierung.de/script/mv_a3_wasserschutz_wms.php?

The following lines only show the OSM base map, but not the WMS layer.

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(lat = 53.8, lng = 12.6, zoom = 8) %>% 
              addWMSTiles("http://www.umweltkarten.mv-regierung.de/script/mv_a3_wasserschutz_wms.php?", 
              layers = "t3_wsg", 
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", version = "1.3.0"))
```

Comment: Your WMS does not support Leaflet's default CRS `EPSG:3857`. List of supported CRS [here](https://www.umweltkarten.mv-regierung.de/script/mv_a3_wasserschutz_wms.php?REQUEST=getCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0). I haven't found anything on reprojecting WMS with R and Leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

It should work using the develop version of **mapview**.

```
    library("devtools")
    install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview", ref = "develop")
```

First you have to define the parameters of your online service. This is more ore less tricky. Especially in the case of the  LUNG WMS Server, because it is not setup very OGC conform. To deal with this topic you will find some explanations at the `projView` [vignette](http://gisma.github.io/projView/projView1_0_9.html).

If you analyse the  [getCapabilities output](https://www.umweltkarten.mv-regierung.de/script/lung_wms_wms.php?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS) you'll find the supported projections.

You can use the example list from the package `data("map.types") as a blueprint for further enhancements or adaptions. The LUNG WMS Server is integrated as an use case.

Then you may load an arbitrary `sp*` object you want to map. I took the GADM level2 data for Germany.
        library(mapview)
        library(raster)

```
    # get Germany boundary
    ger<-getGeoData('GADM', country='DEU', level=1)

    # define service
    data("map.types")

    # create map
    projView(ger, map.types= map.types$LMV)
```

The result should look like this:

[image]